# Is it normal that JavaScript can create otherwise invalid DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Somewhat by accident, I found out that a span inserted directly inside a tbody stays in place when done with JavaScript (insertBefore), where such invalid DOM would if created with literal HTML lead to the span being placed before the entire table.

I expected either the same behaviour as with literal HTML or some DOM Exception being thrown.

E.g. this HTML

```html
<table>
    <thead><tr><th>Table Header</th></td></thead>
    <tbody>
        <span>from HTML &rarr; goes up</span>
        <tr><td>Table Contents</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

with this JavaScript:

```js
var span = document.createElement('span'),
    tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');
span.innerHTML = 'Created with JS &rarr; stays in place';
tbody.insertBefore(span, tbody.querySelector('tr'));
```

renders "Created with JS → stays in place" between the header and the first row; the original, literal, span moves outside of the table.

Is this normal, and can/should I count on this? (It behaves the same in FF, Chrome, Opera, IE >= 9 (not tested below)).

Also, is there a way to query the DOM whether content of a certain type would (under normal circumstances) be valid at a certain point in the DOM? This is actually what I wanted to do when I found out about this quirk (which it is, imho).

The fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/xr37g9kw/2/

Comment: Doing this probably pushes the browser into quirks mode

Comment: DOM is a very generic model to represent tree like structures. It doesn't actually include any validation.

Comment: DOM itshelf let you make this kind of mistakes, if that would throw an error, also declaring it straight with `html` would have to throw an error. Browser vendors are relaxed on these kind of "errors"

Comment: I would say that if you're interested in DOM validation, really the only reliable source you have is [this one](https://validator.w3.org/). Don't expect browsers to conform perfectly, however.

Comment: You should absolutely _NOT_ rely on this. It's unfortunate that browsers let this pass without throwing an exception and forcing the author to fix issues with the DOM but you should treat HTML as a proper formal language and follow its rules. Don't rely on the browser dumbly trying to fix problems in random ways.

Comment: To elaborate a bit on my comment: DOM doesn't allow you to create *invalid DOM*. E.g. you won't be able to add a child node to a Text node. However, because DOM is generic, it doesn't know anything about the semantics or validation of the markup language of the original document.

Comment: @xxbbcc: Petition to bring XHTML back from the dead.

Comment: @BoltClock At this point I'm not sure it'd change much.

Comment: @FelixKling lets be more explicit; _Invalid HTML_ is **not** _invalid DOM_

Comment: Thanks all for clarifying the difference between DOM and HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As for *"is this normal, and can/should I count on this?"* Sadly, yes. But mostly you should be aware of the node types you are working with. NB, in case of `table`, there are a handful of not so well known DOM methods (HTMLTableElement.rows. InsertRow() and so on).

As for *"is there a way to query the DOM whether content of a certain type would (under normal circumstances) be valid at a certain point in the DOM?"* nothing built-in for this exact purpose, but you could exploit one native feature of JavaScript -> DOM API: you can let browser to re-parse HTML chunk in the "literal way". Yes, I am speaking about **innerHTML**.

In your fiddle, adding**`tbody.outerHTML = tbody.outerHTML`** ["fixes" the structure](http://jsfiddle.net/xr37g9kw/4/), so you could hypothetically take some DOM node, look at its DOM tree, clone, "re-eval" it and compare with original.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the default behavior, as you saw. It's not valid HTML of course as you can check here http://www.freeformatter.com/html-validator.html if you input the HTML.