# HTML: Anchor in table

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I was trying to make a table with anchor clickable rows. My first try was this:

```html
<table>
    <body>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</td>
                    <th>Name</td>
                    <th>Address</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                    <a href="https://google.com">
                       <td> 1 </td>
                       <td> Google </td>
                       <td> https://google.com </td>
                    </a>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</table>
```

When I inspected the result in Chrome and Edge I noticed that the browsers had decided to split the anchor out and throw it behind the table!

So, this is my first question: Why do browsers manipulate the HTML structure?

My second try was using JavaScript:

```js
var tbody = document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
    var anchor = document.createElement("a");
    anchor.href = "https://google.com"
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerHTML = "1"
    anchor.appendChild(td);
    td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerHTML = "Google";
    anchor.appendChild(td);
    td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerHTML = "https://google.com";
    anchor.appendChild(td);
    tbody.appendChild(anchor);
```

```css
th {
width: 30%;
text-align: left;
}

a {
display: table-row;
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</td>
                <th>Name</td>
                <th>Address</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

It works like a charm: the entire row is clickable.

But I don't get why this time, the browsers don't manipulate with DOM? This is my second question.

Any helpful explanation is appreciated.

Comment: _“Why do browsers manipulate the HTML structure?”_ - because they are trying to correct the _errors_ you introduced. You can not have a link at this position “between” table row and table cells, that is simply not allowed in HTML.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it normal that JavaScript can create otherwise invalid DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33613970/is-it-normal-that-javascript-can-create-otherwise-invalid-dom)

Comment: As loose as it is, HTML actually has rules. If you break these rules, browsers do their best to fill in the gaps, sometimes with unpredictable and undesirable results

Answer (score 2):

> Why do browsers manipulate the HTML structure?

Because your HTML is invalid.

A `<tbody>` element is **only** allowed `<tr>` children.

The parsing rules browsers follow describe how to deal with invalid HTML in that way.

> But I don't get why this time, the browsers don't manipulate with DOM?

The browser isn't building the DOM using the HTML parsing algorithm.

You are manually creating a DOM that represents invalid HTML.

Comment: Also important for the OP to note that the `a` tag is also **not** a valid child for `tr`, so `<tr><a><td></td><</a></tr>` will also not work. So no trying to sneak the `a` tag there.

Answer (score 1):

you can able to redirect using `data-href="your-link.com"`

you can not modify any `<table>` **element** but you want to redirect on tr click

Please check working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hardik_g_/cmqpyejh/)

**HTML CODE**

```
<table>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Address</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <tr class="link" data-href="https://stackoverflow.com/">
                   <td> 1 </td>
                   <td> Google </td>
                   <td> https://google.com </td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
td,th{
  border:1px solid #ddd;
  
}
tbody tr:hover{
  color:red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
table{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

**jQuery CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var link = $(".link").attr("data-href");
  $('.link').click(function(){
    window.location.href=link;
  })
});
```

Comment: While I'm a fan of the data attribute, the downside to this approach is you lose a bit of SEO-ness and accessibility by removing the `<a href="">` in its entirity

Answer (score 0):

So you want the table rows clickable going to a link in that row.

**Don't** wrap the row with an `a` tag. It's invalid, and at best will result in unpredictable results.

You will need javascript to make this work. Add an event listener to the table rows. Check for a well formed `a` tag and redirect to its `href` attribute.

```js
//Get rows
let rows = document.querySelectorAll(".clickRows tbody > tr");

for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  //Add Event listener to row
  rows[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    //If there is a link
    if (this.querySelector("a[href]")) {
      //Redirect to it
      window.location.href = this.querySelector("a[href]").href;
    } else {
      console.log("No Link");
    }
  })
}
```

```css
th {
  width: 30%;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<table class="clickRows">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <!-- You had mismatched th and td tags here -->
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> 1 </td>
      <td> Google </td>
      <td><a href="https://google.com">https://google.com</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> 2 </td>
      <td> Ding </td>
      <td>Ding</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you are willing to drop the HTML table

```css
/*Displat as table*/
.clickRows {
  display:table;
  width:30%;
}


/*Set appropriate children as rows*/
.clickRows > div, .clickRows > a
{
  display:table-row;
}

/*Then set the cells*/
.clickRows > div > div, .clickRows > a > div
{
  display:table-cell;
  
}

.head {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="clickRows">
  <div class="head">    
      <!-- You had mismatched th and td tags here -->
      <div>Id</div>
      <div>Name</div>
      <div>Address</div>
    </div>
  <a href="https://google.com">
      <div> 1 </div>
      <div> Google </div>
      <div>https://google.com</div>
  </a>
  <div>
      <div> 2 </div>
      <div> Ding </div>
      <div>Ding</div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

On a side note your HTML as provided is quite broken. `body` is not a valid child element for `table`. Opening and closing `td` and `th` must match. For more info on what is and isn't valid for `table` and it's associated elements, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table)